# Is it possible to determine when a stored procedure was last modified in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know that you can do this in SQL Server 2005, but I'm at a loss for 2000.

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.

To get around this, I manage my stored procedures in a Visual Studio database project.  Every stored procedure is in its own file and has a drop command at the top of the file.  When I update the stored through Visual Studio, the database's created date is updated in the database because of the drop/create statement.  I am able to use the created date in SQL Server 2000 as the last modified date in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

From all the research I've done on this in the past, I unfortunately have to say no. SQL Server 2000 simply does not store this information, and I've never seen any solution for retrieving it.

There are a few alternative methods, but they all involve user intervention. Besides keeping stored procedure scripts in a source control system, I think the next best approach is to use comments inside the stored procedure. Not ideal, but it's better than nothing if you want to track what gets updated.

Comment: chrissuire's solution sounds like a good one too. Same caveats.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT crdate
FROM   sysobjects 
WHERE  name = 'proc name here' 
AND    type = 'P'
```

Comment: It is Create date, not modify (by ALTER PROCEDURE...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use : SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

Found here : [Date object last modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78471/date-object-last-modified/2342967#comment33469725_2342967)