# How to check date of last change in stored procedure or function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I need to check when function was changed last time. I know how to check creation date (it is in function properties window in SQL Server Management Studio).
I found that in SQL Server 2000 it wasn't possible to check modify date ( look at this post: [Is it possible to determine when a stored procedure was last modified in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163957/is-it-possible-to-determine-when-a-stored-procedure-was-last-modified-in-sql-serv))

Is it possible to check it in SQL Server 2008? Does MS add some new feature in system tables that allow to check it?

Answer (score 463, accepted):

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

The `type` for a function is `FN` rather than `P` for procedure. Or you can filter on the name column.

Comment: it seems that certain permissions can cause results to be omitted from this query - even though there are some results that return.  We have observed different results based on user authority - but I haven't narrowed it down to which authorities are involved.  Long story short: run this query as SA if you can to make sure you are seeing everything.

Comment: You are indeed correct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324%28v=sql.105%29.aspx "In SQL Server 2005 and later versions, the visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For more information, see Metadata Visibility Configuration."

Comment: A word of warning. If the OP is referring exclusively to changes to a module  made via an ALTER DDL statement, then `modify_date` can be misleading. For example, if `sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule` is executed on the module, the `modify_date` will be changed even though technically the code of the module has not changed.

Comment: how may get the Specified Database Stored Procedures only?!

Comment: @im_one After the WHERE line, add `AND name = 'specified procedure'` where `specified procedure` is the name of the stored proc you want to find.

Answer (score 50):

Try this for stored procedures:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND name = 'myProc'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this is simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 16):

This is the correct solution for finding a function:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'fn'
AND name = 'fn_NAME'
```

Answer (score 13):

I found this listed as the new technique

This is very detailed

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' 
order by  LAST_ALTERED desc

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' 
order by  CREATED desc 


SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'FUNCTION' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' 
order by  LAST_ALTERED desc

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'FUNCTION' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' 
order by  CREATED desc
```

Comment: Curious why you would want to pull from this view instead of using sys.objects. Is this so you can get extra details on the functions/procedures?

I will say I noticed in one DB the sys.objects showed a different modify date compared to the information_schema.routines alter date...

Comment: @Izulien: The views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA are part of the SQL standard so should exist across different relational database management systems.  sys.objects and sys.procedures are specific to SQL Server.  Which one someone uses may depend on how portable they want their code to be.  I don't know anything about the implementation in SQL Server so don't know why the modify dates might be different between INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES and sys.objects.  For more info on INFORMATION_SCHEMA see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema

Answer (score 8):

In latest version(2012 or more) we can get modified stored procedure detail by using this query

```
SELECT create_date, modify_date, name FROM sys.procedures 
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

Comment: Already [using sys.procedures to search for text in sprocs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360448/3585500) so nice I could get the dates.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL 2000 I would use:

```
SELECT name, crdate, refdate 
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P' 
ORDER BY refdate desc
```

Comment: What about 2008..? Isn't that the question..?

Comment: @NREZ queries on sysobjects are supported on 2008 so this will work

Comment: refdate is not the last modified date. Check the date difference between sys.object and sysobjects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for check modify date of `functions` and `stored procedures` together ordered by date :

```
SELECT 'Stored procedure' as [Type] ,name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P' 

UNION all

Select 'Function' as [Type],name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'FN'
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

or :

```
SELECT type ,name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type in('P','FN') 
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
-- this one shows type like : FN for function and P for stored procedure
```

Result will be like this :

```
Type                 |  name      | create_date              |  modify_date
'Stored procedure'   | 'firstSp'  | 2018-08-04 07:36:40.890  |  2019-09-05 05:18:53.157
'Stored procedure'   | 'secondSp' | 2017-10-15 19:39:27.950  |  2019-09-05 05:15:14.963
'Function'           | 'firstFn'  | 2019-09-05 05:08:53.707  |  2019-09-05 05:08:53.707
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type IN ('FN', 'IF', 'TF') 
AND name = 'dgdsgds'
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, created_at, updated_at 
FROM table_name.column_name
WHERE type = 'soemthing'
ORDER BY updated_at DESC ;
```

I hope This will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).