# Find out who modified a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way using tsql to tell who was the last person to modify a stored procedure?

I am trying to find my changes versus my co-workers.

Comment: See if answers here help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d655e549-c570-4944-b56c-5c28ee942f2b/who-modified-my-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql

Comment: If it's **code** like for a stored procedure, I hope you're using a **source control system** that tracks this. Otherwise, you'd have to have DDL triggers in place that report who changed what when

Comment: Code here is useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/258111/finding-out-who-has-modified-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking at the last modification date. If you know who was logged in to their system at the time it can help narrow down your suspects.

Credit goes to Chris Diver: [How to check date of last change in stored procedure or function in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579223/how-to-check-date-of-last-change-in-stored-procedure-or-function-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
```

The type for a function is FN rather than P for procedure. Or you can filter on the name column.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested solution with sys.objects can provide the information about the person who modified a stored procedure

> I am trying to find my changes versus my co-workers.

This information is not available when using this query.To find your changes vs the changes your colleagues made, you can use:

- a source control system
- read the online transaction log to see who did what and when on your stored procedure

For the latter one, you can use the fn_dblog function, or a third party tool such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

*Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL*