# How to write a SQL query to get all modified dates of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get all modified dates (n modified dates) of a stored procedure.

Though I am able to get last modified date of a stored procedure like this:

```
select name, create_date, modify_date 
from sys.procedures 
where name = 'SPF_OLS_GET_CUSTOMER_SUMMARY' 
order by modify_date desc;
```

but I want to get all modified dates. Is it possible? If yes, then how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, SQL Server doesn't track history like that. One last modified date is all you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check date of last change in stored procedure or function in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579223/how-to-check-date-of-last-change-in-stored-procedure-or-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: As Jeroen wrote in his comment, SQL Server doesn't track such history changes. If you need such information, you can write a DDL trigger that will catch the modification of the procedure and record it into a change log table.

Comment: SQL Server does not keep these changes.  That is not what it is designed to do.  As such we always keep the SQL statements in a source code repository (TFS, Subversion, git, etc).  SQL changes are installed from the repository so a history can be kept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

[image]

Comment: This would only be the last modified date, not a history of each date the procedure was modified.

Comment: Please check modified answer, where I get both dates

Comment: @Shivani I want each date that of Stored procedure modified as Tom said

Comment: @Shivani.  Your code is getting the latest change dates for each stored procedure on a database.  This is not what the OP is asking.  He's looking for all change dates for a particular stored procedure.  For this he'll need to use some type of source code repository outside of SQL Server.