# view when table or view last altered, sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, triggers

Is there a an easy way to see(timestamp) when a database was last altered within a sql 2000 instance? Apparently the solution is not as simple as 2005 where i can query the "sys.tables."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible out of the box with SQL server 2000.  See this SO question for more information: **[Date object last modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78471)**.